# Microsoft Enterprise Logging Block with Entity Framework asks for WriteLog procedure

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, logging, enterprise-library

I have a WCF service that uses Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging to log some messages to the Event Log. That works just fine.

The problem is that i want to log some messages to a table in an Oracle database. I am using the Entity Framework to communicate with that Oracle database.

The next step is a right click on the 'web.config' and choose the option 'Edit Enterprise Configuration'. I get the 'Enterprise Library Configuration' editor. In there i am trying to set the Logging Settings so that it also logs to the database, but  when i add a database trace listener it´s asking me to fill in a procedure name. Do i have to add a procedure name to fill the table in Oracle? The msdn tells me to run the script that create an MSSQL database 'Logging' and some tables. But i don't have an MSSQL server, i have an Oracle server. And i don't want to use a seperate logging database, but save the logs to a single table.

Can anybody help me with this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The Enterprise Library Database Trace Listener uses 2 stored procedures to write to the database: Add Category Procedure and Write To Log Procedure.

There is a [SQL Server script](http://entlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/90009#527585) to create the tables and stored procedures.  This would have to be ported to Oracle.

Unfortunately, it looks like this does not work as easily as you would hope.  See the blog post, [Enterprise Library Logging to Oracle Database](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/05/21/enterprise-library-logging-to-oracle-database/) (this is based on EntLib 3, I believe) and the work item [Cannot log to oracle Database using logging blocks](http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/28946) for a description of some of the issues as well as some downloads to help.